# Why is there an être in "je pense être super cool"?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, expressions, négation, conjugaison

---

> French help

---

Why does the "*être*" mean "I am"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Cela signifie très exactement : *Je pense **que je suis** super cool.*

Answer (score 1):

Just to maybe draw connections with other languages... this is probably a vestige of the [complementary infinitive](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/complementary-infinitive) in classical languages. Essentially the verb "think" asks for a complement of sorts ("I think... what?"), and the infinitive could be used to complete such verbs.

We could actually do something similar in English...

> I think myself to be very cool.

Basically, as has already been indicated, it is indeed an alternative form of

> Je pense *que je suis* très cool.

Comment: Ok thanks very much.